# the following code is giving an UnboundLocalError , Local variable referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def take_command():
    try:
        with nc.Microphone()as source:
            print('listening....')
            voice = listener.listen(source)
            command = listener.recognise_google(voice)
            command = command.lower()
        if 'Esy' in command:
            command = command.replace('Esy', '')
            print(command)
    except:
        pass
    return command
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. It is great that you included the text based code that you have. As python in a language where space is significant, can you use the `{}` code tool to format it?  That would help others with helping you. Additionally, can you include the exact error you have? It probably has pointers to the problem.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to return `command` after the `except` block. In this case the compiler assumes that in case of an error before assigning anything to `command` will execute that code and will not have a value for `command`

So, let's say that`voice = listener.listen(source)` will fail somehow. Here the `try` block will stop (so the `command` will not be initialized) and will execute the `except` block, and then you want to return `command`, which as I mentioned, is not initialized yet.